# Is publish_actions required to post on user own wall? Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When requesting **publish_actions** permission the message says **the app is willing to post on your friends' wall** but I actually just want my app to let the user post videos on his own wall. Do I need this permission to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to share a Link (to a Youtube Video, for example), you can just use the Share Dialog - no authorization or permissions needed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

If you want to upload a photo or video, you will need to authorize the user with `publish_actions`. Keep in mind that the message must be 100% user generated.

Check out the "Publishing" part of the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/videos

> A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new photos.

...well, that is actually a bug in the docs, it should be "videos", not "photos", of course. I´ve filed a bug report for this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303448543173296/

General information about sharing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share

Comment: my app will post video on user's wall from internal form using FBRequest. no worry it's 100% user generated post

Comment: Thank I've spend a lot of time so far to get around this api. so much contradictory information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use standards dialogs? According to the facebook api documentation you don't need this permission for theses dialogs.

(see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-publish_actions)

If you use the Facebook Graph API you don't need this permission if you only want to post on the user feed.

Comment: I will only make FBRequest to me/videos. I will not use standards dialogs